# Как сделать ограничение на нажатие кнопок в Unity для игры викторины?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Суть такая, делаю игру викторину, где на вопрос есть четыре ответа, и необходимо сделать так, чтобы игрок, когда нажал на какую-то кнопку с ответом, не мог нажать на другую до появления следующего вопроса. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему через цикл foreach. Забыл ещё добавить в вопросе, что у меня кнопки в массиве "GameObject[] options";

```
foreach (var a in options)
{
    a.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
}
```